# How to handle aws Lambda retry in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

According to AWS retry documentation 
"
Poll-based (or pull model) event sources that are stream-based: These consist of Kinesis Data Streams or DynamoDB. When a Lambda function invocation fails, AWS Lambda attempts to process the erring batch of records until the time the data expires, which can be up to seven days.

The exception is treated as blocking, and AWS Lambda will not read any new records from the shard until the failed batch of records either expires or is processed successfully. This ensures that AWS Lambda processes the stream events in order.
"
But we need different functionality, We are inserting records in mysql aurora and if anything is fail in lambda then same event processed multiple time from kinesis and we end up to have duplicates records in database. How we can handle this.

thanks

Comment: I have some query regarding kinesis lambda if some error occurred I do not want to retry means just that particular record and transfer it to some destination for further investigation. The purpose of this process is to stop duplicate record insertion from kinesis to mysql db.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to add some try/catch exception handling logic in your Lambda function code, so that the exception never surfaces to the Lambda service.